# Prove this Fibonacci sum is less than 12

Tags: inequality, fibonacci-numbers

Going through some old math notes, I saw this problem.

Prove that $$\frac{1}{F(1)} + \frac{2}{F(2)} + \cdots + \frac{n}{F(n)} < 13.$$

I did not write down a proof, but I did scratch down the inequality $F(n) > \phi^{n-2}$ which tells me each term can be bounded-$$\frac{n}{F(n)} < \frac{n}{\phi^{n-2}}.$$ I have played around with the inequality, and tried different bounds like $\frac{3}{2} < \phi$ but I haven't been able to prove this inequality.

Comment: You can use that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \alpha^{k - 1} = 1/(1-\alpha)^2$ for $\alpha \in (-1, 1)$

Comment: 12, or 13? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MJD on my notes, I wrote down 13. This was years ago though; it could be a typo.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but then noticed that @DiegoSilvera had already written a comment about my point. With this estimation one can easily get the upper bound as $\phi^5\approx 11.09$

Comment: @DiegoSilvera, thank you for reminding me to manipulate the sum equation. Using that method, I was able to get a bound of $\frac{1}{5\phi -8}$. Which as A.Gamma found as well, it's roughly 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $n$ large enough, we have $F_n\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^n$ by the explicit (Binet's) formula for Fibonacci numbers and the fact that $\varphi >\frac{8}{5}$. Here *large enough* simply means $\geq 4$, hence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n}{F_n}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{3}\frac{n}{F_n}+\sqrt{5}\sum_{n\geq 4}\frac{n}{\left(\frac{8}{5}\right)^n}=\frac{9}{2}+\frac{10625 \sqrt{5}}{4608}<\color{red}{10}. $$

Comment: This also aligns with the result I got from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%2F(F_n)+from+n+%3D+1+to+n+%3D+infinity), which shows that the bound converges near $10$ if you click 'More Terms' many, many times.

Comment: And seriously (assuming you're in Italy), what are you doing at 2 am?

Comment: @TobyMak: as I declared during the election, *I do not sleep much*. That's true :D

Comment: If you're wondering why I'm not asleep, here in Hong Kong it's 9 am (Sunday morning).

Comment: Great solution Jack!